# Setting Thread's name in constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

Which approach is more appropriate: setting a thread's name in a ctor by calling `super(name)` or by invoking `setName(name)`?

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    MyThread(String name){
//        super(name);      // which one is preferable?
//        setName(name);
    }
    public void run(){ /* business logic */ }
}
```

Would calling `setName()` in a ctor involve side effects? The reason I'm asking is that most tutorials use `super(name)` but I remember watching a video on YouTube where a college prof was always putting `setName()` right in the ctor...

Comment: Well, the compiler would automatically call `super()` anyway, so you might as well do `super(name)`. Just good convention, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No major difference except that if you will not be able to call `setName()` after Thread instantiation if either thread's state is NEW or the [access privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) to that thread is changed. In short, it's better to set name during Thread instantiation itself to avoid surprises.